# Using a gem with middleman, is it possible?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, middleman

I'm working on a newsletter, when I'm done with it I want to inline all the css code.
There are online tools that do that, like:

- http://zurb.com/ink/inliner.php
- http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css

but I want to do it within `middleman` and have the build version of my newsletter ready to be sent, I found couple or more of gems that can help with that, But I'm not sure how to use it with `middleman` or if its even possible. Here is one of the gems I'm talking about:

- https://github.com/maca/inline-style

Can be used with `middleman`? if yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

I never actually used middleman but with a fast read I think I got a solution for you

You should be able to use the rack middleware from `inline-style` on middleman

http://middlemanapp.com/advanced/rack-middleware/

You should add `use InlineStyle::Rack::Middleware` if you want it for all routes.

Comment: so basically I just install the gem and add this line of code, and it should work?

Answer (score 0):

Middleman is a static site generator and is usually deployed without using middleware at all. That does not mean you can not deploy middleman in such a way, but after a build middleman spits out flat html files that your webserver just needs to send to the client. It’s static.

The easiest way to inline a file during the build process is probably `IO::read` like so:

`<%= IO.read("path/to/file.ext") %>`

You would have to check how this works when the file should be preprocessed with Sass or CoffeeScript since by default middleman adds a cache buster so you don’t know the final name of the compressed file.